# "Optimal Strategy: Setting Classification Threshold in the Model vs. During Prediction"

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, classification, prediction

I'm working on a binary classification task and would like to understand the best practices for incorporating class thresholds into my model. Specifically, I want to ensure that the model not only makes binary predictions but also provides a measure of its level of confidence in each prediction.
I'm considering two approaches:

1. **Threshold within the Model**: Incorporate the class threshold directly into the model architecture, so it makes binary predictions based on whether the probability is above or below the threshold.

```py
import torch.nn as nn

class CustomBinaryClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, threshold=0.5):
        super(CustomBinaryClassifier, self).__init()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.threshold = threshold

    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.linear(x)
        probabilities = self.sigmoid(logits)
        # Apply threshold for class assignment
        classes = (probabilities >= self.threshold).float()
        return classes

# Create an instance of the model with a specified threshold
threshold = 0.5
model = CustomBinaryClassifier(in_features=X.shape[1], threshold=threshold)
```

2. **Threshold as a Post-processing Step**: Calculate class probabilities from the model's raw logits and apply a threshold as a post-processing step to determine the binary class assignment.

```py
import torch

# Assuming you have a trained model 'model' and input data 'X_test'
untrained_preds = model(X_test)
untrained_preds_probs = torch.sigmoid(untrained_preds)

threshold = 0.5
predicted_classes = (untrained_preds_probs >= threshold).float()
```

1. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach, and when should I use one over the other? Additionally, if I use the threshold within the model, does it affect the model's learning process and its ability to be confident in its predictions?
2. And one more thing, if I include the confidence calculations (like probabilities ) within the model (as in approach 1 ie,sigmoid), does it change the way I calculate the loss while training? Does it make the model better at estimating its level of confidence in its predictions and improving its accuracy?

I'm looking for practical advice on how and when to set class thresholds in binary classification models.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use thresholding within the model, as it will impact training. Your loss function needs a soft output (from logits or sigmoid of logits), giving a hard output destroys the gradient signal. You should read more into how binary cross entropy works.

In terms of setting a threshold, this is typically done after training based on desired metrics. Your threshold gives you the ability to tune precision/recall of the model. Imagine sweeping the threshold from 0 to 1. At 0, you have terrible precision (lots of false positives), but perfect recall (no false negatives). At 1, it's the opposite.

You should first determine what metric is most important for your application (precision, recall, F1, etc). Then, after training the model, sweep the range of thresholds on your validation set and see what value gives the best metric. You can also look at things like ROC curves.